# stateful drawable not finding other drawables

Tags: android

When creating a stateful drawable, I cannot find the other drawables (9-patch images) that are there - i get no "suggestions" ("intelliSense").

But if I try to find drawables in another XML-file there is no problem.

this is my stateful drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:state_focused="true"
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/view_background_pressed" />
<item
    android:state_focused="true"
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/view_background_normal" />
<item
    android:state_focused="false"
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/view_background_pressed" />
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/view_background_normal" />
</selector>
```

the "view_background_pressed" etc are all there, and they can be found in other XML-files but not in the statefule drawable.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

It's quite possible that it's just Eclipse being funny. Have you tried cleaning the project from Project → Clean?
Or restarting Eclipse?

You can also check the output of `aapt` to check that there isn't a subtle resource compilation problem somewhere that you're missing.

You can enable more output in the Eclipse console by going to:
Preferences → Android → Build → Build output → Verbose

Then, as you execute a build (or Eclipse attempts to build automatically), you'll see the `aapt` output in the Console view (you may need to select the Android sub-console).

Comment: Thx for the answer... However, I have tried to Clean and restart Eclipse - same problem. 
I also switched to verbose mode, but I cannot see any errors there. Where can I find the android sub console?

Comment: Press Alt+F3, then type Console to bring up the console. Then under the "Display Selected Console" icon (looks like a computer monitor) in the console, choose Android.

Comment: Oooops sorry, it's Alt+3 (I think). I'm on a Mac just now and it's Cmd+3. Or just Window > Show View > Console.

Answer (score 2):

If you wan't to use custom shapes you need to make them in the same XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:shape="rectangle">    
        <solid
            android:color="@color/lichtblauw"/> 
        <corners
            android:radius="5dp"/>
        <stroke 
            android:width="1px" android:color="@color/donkergrijs" />
    </shape>        
</item> <!-- pressed -->

<item android:state_focused="true">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:shape="rectangle">    
        <solid
            android:color="@color/lichtblauw"/> 
        <corners
            android:radius="5dp"/>
        <stroke 
            android:width="1px" android:color="@color/donkergrijs" />
    </shape> 
 </item> <!-- focused -->

<item>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:shape="rectangle">    
        <solid
            android:color="@color/blauw"/>  
        <corners
            android:radius="5dp"/>
        <stroke 
            android:width="1px" android:color="@color/donkergrijs" />
    </shape>    
</item> <!-- default -->
```