# Change shape and color of ToggleButton(or maybe somthing else)?

Tags: android, selector, drawable

I want a togglebutton that looks like a fire or spark. I want to indicate when the button is selected and when its not.
As far as I know this can be done using a Selector-drawable. Now I want to change color of the "fire" on my button from code. And I want the color to be changed in both the selected and the unselected drawable.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So late, but to next's... the answer is at... [ToggleButton shape not changing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27065051/togglebutton-shape-not-changing/27065773#27065773)

I hope that will be util

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `ToggleButton` and just change the drawable to like like whatever you want.  You'll need to create a stateful drawable.  You can get some information about that at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009970/stateful-drawable-not-finding-other-drawables).