# ToggleButton shape not changing

Tags: java, android

Am trying to make a circular togglebutton with a green background. i used

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval"
    android:visible="true">
    <solid android:color="@color/material_green_A200" />
</shape>
```

for defining the shape and then used

```
android:background="@drawable/circlebutton"
```

to change the shape and color but nothing changes. it shows up with a no background color or shape but the text is visible

Comment: Could you try just putting a color?

Comment: i did and it shows the color and for some reason it even shows the circular button in android studio but on my phone it doesn't

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

**Your activity.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ToggleButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/style_toggle_button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Style Toggle Button(style_toggle_button.xml):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/offcirclebutton" android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/oncirclebutton" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/oncirclebutton" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/oncirclebutton" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/offcirclebutton"/>
</selector>
```

**Style OFF(offcirclebutton.xml):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval"
    android:visible="true">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_orange_dark" />
</shape>
```

**Style ON(oncirclebutton.xml):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval"
    android:visible="true">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_green_dark" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Case you dont see the text, set textOn and textOff to empty. Like this: 

android:textOn=""
android:textOff=""

Comment: Not sure how its color was set ("@color/material_green_A200"). This solution applied to a "system" color in toggle button, according to their state ...